# How to create form from two models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a UserProfile model defined in *settings.py*.
Now I want to create a registration form that has fields from both the **User** and **UserProfile** models. Is there an easy way to do it?

I'm using uni_form to create nice-looking forms if this helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164582/get-user-onetoonefield-fields-in-modelforms/66913779#66913779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put two children of Form in the view and display them in the template. Use the `prefix` argument in the constructors to prevent field name collisions.

Comment: Problem is, my UserProfile has fields that should be visible between fields of User model (like "Title: Mr/Mrs"). Maybe will be easier to create form from UserProfile model and manually add fields missing from User model...

Comment: Or you could just output the fields from the appropriate form yourself, in the order you need them.