# Get user OneToOneField fields in ModelForms

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I've extended the django user with a `OneToOneField` so I can store address and such.

`SiteUser` is the model which extends `User` using a `OneToOneField`. How can I get fields of both `User` and `SiteUser` in a single `ModelForm`?

Here is the relevant code so far:

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    pass
```

View in question:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    username = request.user
    user = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
    profileform_class = ProfileForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        profileform = profileform_class(data=request.POST, instance=user)
        if profileform.is_valid():
            profileform.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        profileform = profileform_class(instance=user)

    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {
        'user': user,
        'profileform': profileform,
    })
```

And the two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product-images', default='default.jpg')
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)


class SiteUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    post_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    post_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
```

HTML Page I want the forms on:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Rediger {{ product.name }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Rediger "{{ user }}"</h1>
  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profileform.as_p }}
    {{ addressform.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One option is to use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Using this, you won't be needing a second `ModelForm`.

  > Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets. These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign key.

  You can find [good examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113047/creating-a-model-and-related-models-with-inline-formsets).
- Alternatively, if you want to avoid inline formsets and use both `ProfileForm` and `AddressForm` under a single `<form>` tag as you have done in your template, you can do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832125/6492916).

  Forms:

  ```
  class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = User
          fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

  class AddressForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
          model = SiteUser
          exclude = ['user']
  ```

  Views:

  ```
  def edit_profile(request):
      username = request.user
      user = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
      profileform_class = ProfileForm
      addressform_class = AddressForm

      if request.method == 'POST':
          profileform = profileform_class(data=request.POST, instance=user)
          addressform = addressform_class(data=request.POST, instance=user.siteuser)
          if all((profileform.is_valid(), addressform.is_valid())):
              user = profileform.save()
              address = addressform.save(commit=False)
              address.user = user
              address.save()
              return redirect('profile')
      else:
          profileform = profileform_class(instance=user)
          addressform = addressform_class(instance=user.siteuser)

      return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {
          'user': user,
          'profileform': profileform,
          'addressform': addressform,
      })
  ```

Comment: So this got me closer to what I wanted, thanks! 

But the problem now is that the addressform does not really know which user it's referring to. Thus the form does not autofill when there already is an address, and it can't save the new address. 

The "User" model in the forms.py already know which one it is cause there can only be one user. But just referring to "SiteUser" won't make it point to the current user. 

In other parts of the script I use user.siteuser to get to the different parts of the model if I want to display it. 

And the "all()" apparently only takes one statement

Comment: @AndreasHalvorsenTollånes Edited my answer to refer to the corresponding SiteUser model. Corrected the call to all(): you're supposed to pass a list/tuple to it, sorry. Tell me if this works :)

Comment: Yes! It now works, but to autofill the fields you want to add the instance=user.siteuser to the else: addressform = addressform_class(instance=user.siteuser) ^^

Comment: @AndreasHalvorsenTollånes Oops, forgot to add it there: done!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about forms, but I think you should use the "initial" parameter when instantiating the AddressForm, as exemplified here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

So you create your AddressForm class with SiteUser as model, and when you instantiate it in the view, you make it like this:

```
AddressForm(initial={'user': request.user})
```

If "username" is not the primary key of the User model, you can get the primary key like this:

```
User.objects.get(username=request.user).pk
```

and then give it in the "initial" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Bike(models.Model):
    to_company = models.OneToOneField(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bike_company")
    name_bike = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

form.py

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ("name", "description" )


class BikeForm(ModelForm):
    name_bike = forms.CharField(required=True)
    model = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta(CompanyForm.Meta):
        model = Company

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        company = super().save(commit=False)
        company.name = self.cleaned_data.get("name")
        company.description = self.cleaned_data.get("description")
        company.save()
        bike = Bike.objects.create(to_company=company)
        bike.name_bike = self.cleaned_data.get("name_bike")
        bike.model = self.cleaned_data.get("model")
        bike.save()
        return company
```

the relationship is kept in this line:

```
Bike.objects.create(to_company=company)
```

here is an example of a different type of user model

models user and type
https://gist.github.com/josuedjh3/259b4b3b03ab195637fe2db3c701edd6

FormModel the User and UserCreationForm

https://gist.github.com/josuedjh3/0c26d989552a82d5b252c5bd3fed1054